# Pass parameter to Azure CLI Task in DevOps

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-devops, command-line-interface, azure-cli

How do you pass a parameter to an Azure CLI Task in Azure DevOps?

Take the very basic example of showing basic info about a VM. A basic CLI command would be:

- az vm show --name myVM  --resource-group dev -o table

Now if I wanted to parameterize that command, so that I could pass in the VM Name, who would i do it?

I've tried creating a CLI Task as both an in-line script and a file, passing parameters using the Azure DevOps Argument builder, but nothing seems to work. The parameter looks like this:

- -vmname "win10-vs"

In the script, I can't get the -vmname parameter, no matter what I try. I've tried:

- $1
- $vmname
- %vmname
- %vmname%

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to use build variables you can use the `$(var_name)` notation, so in your inline script you would use the following:

```
az vm show --name $(my_variable) --resource-group dev -o table
```

if you would launch the script you'd use the same approach. if you are actually talking about how to get parameters in bash script, it should be $1 for the first parameter (as far as I recall)

Comment: How do you read parameters that are sent in to inline scrips via the **arguments** textbox?

Comment: check this thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9416

Comment: Here's the answer:

- For Mac/Linux Hosts, use positional arguments like: $1
- For Windows Hosts, use positional arguments like: %1

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the parameters in "Environment Variables" instead of "Script Arguments"

Inside your script use $myParameter

By the way, I tried what was mentioned in the answer but it didn't work for me.
I'm running a Shell script on a windows host using Azure CLI Task 2.*